# Can I have an if($_POST['submit']){} before the <form method='post'> declaration?

Tags: php, forms, post

Can I have an `if($_POST['submit']){}` before the `<form method='post'>` declaration?

```
 if($_POST['submit']){
     print_r($_POST['submit']);
     $sql="Delete from db where value=2";
     mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    }
 echo"<form method='post'><input type='text' name='text' value='hello!'>
 <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit!'></form>";
```

The problem is, I can not take any sql results when the `if($_POST)` is over the form declaration.

Comment: Any reason to think thats not valid?

Comment: because I have an sql statement in the if($_POST['submit']){} and I must refresh the page to see the sql results. I thought that after the submit the page will be refreshed by itself

Comment: I don't think you're fully understanding the concepts of server-side and client-side code.  *All* of the server-side code, regardless of where it is on the page, gets executed on the server before the page is sent to the client (browser).

Comment: Sql statement? If you mean `$_POST`, that just reads the headers send back by the browser/client.

Comment: yes, when the if($_POST) is over the form declaration, i cannot take any sql results

Comment: @sotirios, This is because you probably try to access your SQL reqults in the form. The page executes from top to bottom. That means that you need to get the SQL result BEFORE you try to put it in the form.

Comment: Why not just try if it works (which is does)?

Comment: the problem was that I was trying to access the sql results in the form before I get them. thank you all!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is valid, but it will throw an error like this

`Notice: Undefined index: submit`

The better practice is to use `isset()`, to check if the post-variable even exists. Then it woud look like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
print_r($_POST['submit']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** that is possible.

Because the POST is send to the server and retrieved with a server side language like `PHP` all the `PHP` gets executed before sending it back to to client. So it doesn't matter where in the file you place the `PHP` to print the POST.